# Can't fire JS properly with addeventlistener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Two examples: [JSfiddle without evenlistener](https://jsfiddle.net/franenos/ym4svbv2/5/) and [JSfiddle with eventlistener](https://jsfiddle.net/franenos/47c8u7uf/3/)

The base code for both of them is:

HTML

```
<body>

</body><p id="one" tabindex="0">ID one of tag P</p>
<input id="two" type="text" value="An input field">
<button id="three">A Button</button>

<p id="showid" tabindex="0"></p>
```

JS

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.activeElement.id;
    document.getElementById("showid").innerHTML = x;
}
```

In order the script will work I added the `onclick="myFunction()"`(see first example at JSF), but if I'm adding an `eventlistener` instead of `onclick="myFunction()"` I'm not getting the proper result.

The JS code with `eventlistener`:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function myFunction() {
    var x = document.activeElement.id;
    document.getElementById("showid").innerHTML = x;
}, false);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Those are very different things. You're adding an event listener for the event `DOMContentLoaded`, which has zero to do with a click event.

Comment: The DOMContentLoaded event triggers on document when the page is ready... Am I missing here something?

Comment: Yes, that you're not doing anything relating to clicks in the second example.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example click event is attached to the body.

```
<body onclick="myFunction()">
```

"**click**" event can be used instead of '**DOMContentLoaded**' to get the same result:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function myFunction() {
    var x = document.activeElement.id;
    document.getElementById("showid").innerHTML = x;
}, false);
```

Comment: Hm... true that. Thanks. But why is it not working with DOMContentLoaded? What should I do in order it to work with DOMContentLoaded?

Comment: Except that this doesn't actually attach the click handler to the button.

Comment: @franenos Attach the event handler to the button?

Comment: @franenos In English your second example means "I want to do something when DOMContentLoaded event is fired." and DOMContentLoaded only gets fired once when the document is loaded and parsed. However click event is fired everytime you click on the document(for this example). I don't think DOMContentLoaded will suit your purpose in this case.

Add alert(x); after var x = ... line and test it for both 'click' and 'DOMContentLoaded' events. You will see the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand but based on your comments and the example I think what you're wondering is how to get your function to execute on the DOMContentLoaded.

Indeed your function is firing on load...

The reason it appears your function isn't firing is because when using the DOMContentLoaded event your 'p' element is not active at the time you are assigning it to x, so x is undefined.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('one').focus();
    var x = document.activeElement.id;
    document.getElementById("showid").innerHTML = x;
}, false);
```

By setting focus first, now your code works.

Comment: So, the 'one' is now showing up on page load...
https://jsfiddle.net/jesselee34/47c8u7uf/5/